# Calculate conditional probability with coin toss

Tags: probability

A coin tossed 10 times.

what is the probability that the coin lands on 'Heads' less than 'Tails' given that the first toss was 'Heads'?

Say X indicating how many times the coin landed on Heads 
Y indicating how many times the coin landed on Tails
B is the event where the first toss lands on 'Heads'.

I need to calculate $P(X<Y | B)$

from conditional probability I know that $P(X<Y | B) = \frac{P((X<Y) \bigcap B)}{P(B)}$

I know that $P(B) = 0.5$

and I think that $P((X<Y) \bigcap B)$ equals to $\sum_{i=0}^4 P((i<10-i) \bigcap B)$

but I'm stuck at this and would appriciate any help.

Comment: So...there are $9$ tosses to go and you need at least $6$ tails. Just sum the cases.

Comment: you can do it without conditional probability (as such) - in the next 9 tosses, you can only have max 3 heads, so it is the probability of 0,1,2 or 3 from 9 tosses (3 or less heads from 9 tosses)

Comment: if you want to use Bayes theorem, P(first toss head and less heads than tails overall) = (1/2)(P(0 from 9 ) + P(1 from 9 ) + P(2 from 9 ) + P(3 from 9 ))   ...   would be P(X and Y) which you would then divide by 1/2 to get the earlier suggested answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is that in 9 remaining  coin tosses you have not more than three Heads. So
$$
P(X \leq 3) = \sum_{i=0}^3 {9 \choose i} \left(\frac 12\right)^i \left(\frac 12\right)^{9-i} = \left(\frac 12\right)^9 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^3 {9 \choose i} \approx 0.25
$$

Comment: do I need to divide by 0.5? because of the conditional probabiity?

Comment: No. @Jynxed  Because when $X_i$ is the indicator that the $i$-th coin is heads, then: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} X_i\leq 4\mid X_1=1) ~&=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1=1, \sum\limits_{i=2}^{10} X_i\leq 3)}{\mathsf P(X_1=1)} \\ & =~ \mathsf P(\sum\limits_{i=2}^{10} X_i\leq 3)\end{align}$$